# stored procedure containing two queries, if one return a set don't run the other

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

What's the syntax for creating a stored procedure that contains two queries, if the first query returns a set of records then don't run the second.  I'm guessing there is going to have to be some test on the count so that if the first query returns a set the second won't run.

I would like to do this:

1. Run query
2. Test result set from first query
3. If count equal to zero then run second query

I always like adding is there a 'correct' way to do this or in fact 'should' this type of stored procedure be constructed or is it generally frowned upon?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [@@ROWCOUNT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) to check and see the number of rows affected with the previous query.

```
DoYourQuery()
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
   YourAlternateQuery()
END
```

As to your question about is this something you should be doing, I think that would be case by case.  It is similar to putting control flow logic inside any other program, sometimes `IF` statements are the correct tool to achieve your goals, but they should not be used in every situation.

Comment: It's one of those situations where I am currently running two queries and testing via c# code which recordset to use, i'm wondering if I can lighten the load by combining the queries and code into one stored procedure, this seems to answer my question nicely - thanks Adam.

Comment: @flavour404 Making fewer calls into SQL is nice, as it reduces the number of round-trips over the network you have to make.  You just have to weigh that against the extra processing that SQL does for you, but in this case, the extra processing appears to be very minimal.